# Get Customer Data By update At Field

Tags: customer, data, get

we try to get customer data By (Updated_At Field),

```
rest/V1/customers/search?&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=updated_at&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=2019-11-01 05:22:56&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=gt&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][field]=updated_at&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][value]=2019-11-01 05:22:56&searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][condition_type]=lt&searchCriteria[currentPage]=1&searchCriteria[pageSize]=100&searchCriteria
```

And The Result Return All Customers.
and try to replace GT And LT Condition By From To Condition, The result is the same
Can any Help Me?

Magento 2.3.3

Comment: remove &searchCriteria after page size and try.

Comment: Thank you very much V. Vish working well.
The problem has been resolved.

Comment: If it resolved the issue then you can accept this as useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to try this one :

> Method Type : GET

> Query String :
>
> /V1/customers?&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=updated_at&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=2019-11-01&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=gteq

Comment: Thanks for your help Dhiren Vasoya. its working . very thanks

Comment: If answer help you please upvote and accept as solution, so it will help other in community as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove &searchCriteria from end of the string. After page size and it should work.

Comment: Thank you very much V. Vish working well. The problem has been resolved